How to type erase `NotificationCenter.Notifications`?
I want to create an asynchronous sequence that emits whenever I receive a notification for some group of notifications (Xcode 16.1 RC). My thought was that the easiest way to do this is to use the merge() method from Apple's swift-async-algorithms package. My initial naive attempt:
    let note1 = NotificationCenter.default.notifications(named: .noteOne) 
    let note2 = NotificationCenter.default.notifications(named: .noteTwo)

    let merged = merge(note1, note2) // ❗️ Conformance of 'Notification' to 'Sendable' is unavailable

The error makes sense; I know that Notification can't be Sendable because of its userInfo property. So I thought I could just map that to something else using
    let note1 = NotificationCenter.default.notifications(named: .noteOne) 
      .map { _ in () }
    let note2 = NotificationCenter.default.notifications(named: .noteTwo)
      .map { _ in () }

    let merged = merge(note1, note2) // ❗️ Conformance of 'Notification' to 'Sendable' is unavailable

This doesn't work; I get the same compilation error. So... how do I do this?

Adding .map { _ in () } doesn't work because AsyncMapSequence<Base, Transformed> only conforms to Sendable if all of these conditions are met:

Base is Sendable
Base.Element is Sendable
Transformed is Sendable

See also the source code.
In this case, the second condition is not met. Notification does not conform to Sendable.
From the source code, this Sendable conformance is actually @unchecked. This is because AsyncMapSequence is designed to take non-Sendable closure (it stores this in a stored property), and the compiler can't tell that this is safe.
In fact, if the closure had been a @Sendable one, then only the first condition is required. Since your closure just maps to (), it is Sendable, so you can write your own AsyncMapSequence that takes a @Sendable closure instead.
Since your closure is also not async, I have written this SyncMapSequence to make things simple,
public struct SyncMapSequence<Base, Transformed>: AsyncSequence where Base: AsyncSequence {
    let f: @Sendable (Base.Element) -> Transformed
    let base: Base
    
    public struct AsyncIterator: AsyncIteratorProtocol {
        var baseIterator: Base.AsyncIterator
        let f: @Sendable (Base.Element) -> Transformed
        
        public mutating func next() async throws -> Transformed? {
            try await baseIterator.next().map(f)
        }
        
    }
    
    public func makeAsyncIterator() -> AsyncIterator {
        AsyncIterator(baseIterator: base.makeAsyncIterator(), f: f)
    }
}

extension SyncMapSequence: Sendable where Base: Sendable {}

extension AsyncSequence {
    func syncMap<Transformed>(transform: @Sendable @escaping (Element) -> Transformed) -> SyncMapSequence<Self, Transformed> {
        SyncMapSequence(f: transform, base: self)
    }
}

Usage:
let note1 = NotificationCenter.default.notifications(named: .noteOne)
    .syncMap { _ in () }
let note2 = NotificationCenter.default.notifications(named: .noteTwo)
    .syncMap { _ in () }

let merged = merge(note1, note2)


Yeah, I was able to do much the same thing with my own custom AsyncSequence. I was hoping to use two APIs, both created by Apple, without having to write 20 lines of boilerplate.

The inability to use async algorithms with a notifications stream is maddening.

Here's a different approach, doubtless a lot less elegant: create a whole new AsyncStream that emits a Void value when a notification arrives.
@MainActor
class NotificationConverter {
    private var continuation: AsyncStream<Void>.Continuation?

    var stream: AsyncStream<Void>!

    init(notificationName name: Notification.Name) {
        stream = AsyncStream<Void> { continuation in
            self.continuation = continuation
        }
        Task {
            for await _ in NotificationCenter.default.notifications(named: name) {
                continuation?.yield()
            }
        }
    }

    func unsubscribe() {
        continuation?.finish()
        continuation = nil
        stream = nil
    }

    deinit {
        continuation?.finish()
        continuation = nil
        stream = nil
    }
}

So, to use it in your case, we'd need to create a converter property for each of your notifications:
let converter1 = NotificationConverter(notificationName: .note1)
let converter2 = NotificationConverter(notificationName: .note2)

Then you can say:
let merged = merge(converter1.stream, converter2.stream)

